# How to convert a String to an Array , digits as its elements?

Tags: javascript

I have a string variable called s "1234" and I want to convert it to 4321. To do this I

I would like to convert "1234" into ["1","2,"3","4"] and then use .reverse() and .join()
methods.

```
let s = "1234";

let splittedS = s.split();

console.log(splittedS)
```

The problem is when I use .split() , I get ["1234"]

but I want to get ["1","2","3","4"] So, which method should I use?

(I am sorry If it is a too simple question)

Comment: The default delimiter is comma. Do you have any commas in the string?

Comment: Think this logically. What's the character that's in between the numbers in your string?

Comment: Oh I forgot to add  "" in the splitter, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Add empty string as argument inside `split` function

```js
let s = "1234";

let splittedS = s.split('');

console.log(splittedS)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let s = "1234";

let splittedS = [...s];

console.log(splittedS)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add some insight to what is going on with your example?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Strong.prototype.split` function but set the splitter as `''`.

```js
let s = "1234";
let splittedS = s.split('');
console.log(splittedS)
```